# How do I update a single instance of an inherited form without updating the other open instances?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inheritance, backgroundworker

Edited 3/23 to include suggested changes and new information.

I have a vb.net Windows form, rptBase, with a statusstrip and a ToolStripStatusLabel tssl1.  Two forms, rpt1 and rpt2, inherit rptBase.

On frmMain I have ListBox1 with:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.Click
    Dim frmRpt As New frmRptBase

    Select Case ListBox1.SelectedIndex
        Case 1
            frmRpt = New frmRpt1()
            frmRpt.Text = "Report 1"
            frmRpt.Show()
        Case 2
            frmRpt = New frmRpt2()
            frmRpt.Text = "Report 2"
            frmRpt.Show()
    End Select
    AddForm(frmRpt)
End Sub
```

I would like to report the progress of the reports but when I update tssl1.text on report 1 it also updates report 2 and vice versa.  How do I update just one or the other?

I have a dictionary and a method to save a reference to the forms

```
Public Sub AddForm(frm As Object)
    m_dctFrms.Add(frm, Str(frm.FormID))
End Sub
```

and a method to update the statusbar

```
Public Sub UpdateStatus(strMsg As String)
    tssl1.Text = strMsg
End Sub
```

I run the program, open report 1, then open report 2, then run report1.

New information:

The report runs in a background worker.  When I call UpdateStatus from the DoWork sub, it works as expected.  When I call UpdateStatus from the ProgressChanged sub, it does not.

Private Sub bw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork

UpdateStatus("This works, only one form updated.")

End Sub

Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bw.ProgressChanged

UpdateStstus("This does not work.  Both form are updated.")

```
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the exact type of `m_colFrms`? I'd expect a dictionary(Of Integer, Form) or dictionary(Of Integer, frmRptBase) here, but it looks like the key and value are **backwards** when you add them.

Comment: Private m_colFrms As New Collection

Comment: You probably want to use a `Dictionary(Of Integer, frmRptBase)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However it did not help.  I tried using Public class variables for the forms to eliminate collection from consideration.  I still have the issue.  I believe it's related the the form inheritance.  Even though I have two separate form instances, they seem to be sharing the same instance of the ToolStripStatusLabel control.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a simple form array (+ simplifie a bit your code) :

```
 Dim arrForm(5) As Form 'set max forms count
   
    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If IsNothing(arrForm(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)) Then
            Dim frmRpt As New frmRptBase
            frmRpt.Text = "Report " & ListBox2.SelectedIndex
            arrForm(ListBox1.SelectedIndex) = frmRpt
            frmRpt.Show()
        End If
    End Sub
 
    Public Sub UpdateStatus(intKey As Integer, strMsg As String)
        Dim frm As frmRptBase = arrForm(intKey)
        frm.tssl1.Text = strMsg
    End Sub
```